# Using common Rate action to custom object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a website on which users can rate a concert and I'd like to post this action on the user's timeline.

But since facebook already has common Rate action only for books and videos, I cannot find a way to do this.

I see two alternatives (but I don't know if they're possible):

1. Using the common rate action on a custom object (for example, a music festival in my website)
2. Creating another action which is similar to rate just so I can publish on facebook (it is kind of cheating, but I can't really see another way)

I'd like to know which is the better way to go now, or if there's another alternative.

Comment: 1. You can't use common rate book or rate video action on a custom object.

2. I don't believe that this will be a satisfying solution. Because it will look different to common rating. I found a property named ´review´ for a custom object. But there's no documentation for this property.

Comment: I created a bug report at facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/254563538027575 <- click repro if you want a solution

Comment: I clicked repro there, but the answers given by Anton doesn't solve the problem yet.

Comment: Well, they said they'll take it as feature request. And the property `review` only works in combination with books/videos. No good news for us. I think we just have to wait for facebook to extend this rating feature for custom actions.

Answer (score 2):

Since facebook only allows rating for books and videos yet, you could use in your facebook story symbols like ✪ or ✭.

So you only need to write them dynamically into your user story, user feed or the way you let your user post their ratings. I think when you put them into headline, they'll be big enough.

Here are some stars: ✩ ✪ ✫ ✬ ✭ ✮ ✯ ✰

I know that it is just a bad workaround, but as soon as I'll know that facebook changed their rating system, I'll update this answer.